# Exercício do livro Eloquent JavaScript

Tags: javascript, loop

Olá, sou iniciante em programação. Estou utilizando para meus estudos em JavaScript o livro **Eloquent JavaScript**. Não compreendo o funcionamento do código abaixo:

#### Código

```js
var JOURNAL = [
   {
      "events":["carrot","exercise","weekend"],
      "squirrel":false
   },
   ...
];

function hasEvent(event, entry) {
   return entry.events.indexOf(event) != -1;
}

function tableFor(event, journal) {
   var table = [0, 0, 0, 0];
   for (var i = 0; i < journal.length; i++) {
      var entry = journal[i], index = 0;
      if (hasEvent(event, entry)) index += 1;
      if (entry.squirrel) index += 2;
      table[index] += 1;
   }
   return table;
}
console.log(tableFor("pizza", JOURNAL)); // → [76, 9, 4, 1]
```

#### JOURNAL

https://eloquentjavascript.net/2nd_edition/code/jacques_journal.js

#### Minha dúvida

De modo geral, sei que a função percorre o loop em busca do registro que corresponda ao evento determinado no argumento. Porém, como ela chega a esse resultado é uma incógnita para mim e pra variar não encontrei material pra tirar minhas dúvidas.

Comment: `JOURNAL` seria oq exatamente?

Comment: É um array. O código completo tá aqui: https://eloquentjavascript.net/2nd_edition/code/jacques_journal.js

Comment: Por favor coloque na pergunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function hasEvent(event, entry) {
   /*
   Retorna true/false se o array "events" do objeto "entry" contém o "event".
   Aqui, verifica-se se o índice em que o event está. Caso não exista o event selecionado,
   ele retorna -1.
   Na maioria dos casos 0 é um retorno equivalente à false no JS, mas como esta função
   retorna um índice e 0 é um índice válido, para não gerar confusão, aqui é retornado -1
   */

   return entry.events.indexOf(event) != -1;
}

function tableFor(event, journal) {
   // Esta é tabela de ocorrência de eventos
   var table = [0, 0, 0, 0];

   // Percorre o array
   for (var i = 0; i < journal.length; i++) {
      // entry é um objeto dentro de journal
      // index é definido como o primeiro índice da tabela
      var entry = journal[i], index = 0;

      // Se o event informado existe, adiciona 1 ao índice do array.
      // Se for true, index agora é 1 e aponta para o segundo índice da tabela 
      if (hasEvent(event, entry)) index += 1;

      // Se a propriedade squirrel for true, adiciona 2 ao índice do array.
      // Se for true, index agora é 2 e aponta para o terceiro índice da tabela, mas se
      // a condição anterior também for true, index será na verdade 3 e apontará para
      // a quarta posição da tabela.
      if (entry.squirrel) index += 2;

      // Seleciona o índice que foi calculado anteriormente e soma um ao seu valor
      table[index] += 1;
   }
   return table;
}
```

Comment: Agradeço :) tudo ficou mais claro agora.